# AWS: security groups ignoring traffic from elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have 2 AWS instances, `i-1` and `i-2`. They are each on a different security group: `sg-1` and `sg-2`, respectively. Both machines have elastic IPs.

`sg-2` is configured to allow all traffic from `sg-1`, regardless of port, source IP or protocol.

When `i-1` tries to talk to `i-2` its traffic is being blocked. It seems AWS doesn't account for the fact that `i-1`'s traffic is actually coming from its elastic IP.

Is this expected? Is there anything I can do to work around it, apart from manually adding `i-1`'s elastic IP to `sg-2`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> sg-2 is configured to allow all traffic from sg-1

When you do this, only traffic from Private IP address is allowed. However, as you as using EIP, you explicitly need to allow traffic from that ip address.

Read this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=414060

Quoting from above link:

> Out of curiosity, are you perhaps connecting using a public IP address? When you use a rule with a security group as the source, it will only match when connecting over the internal network. The private IP address can change though. If you have an Elastic IP associated with the instance, the public DNS name happens to be static and will always resolve to the current private IP address when used from within the same EC2 region. That allows you to easily connect internally without worrying about any address changes.

Comment: Thanks. Such a shame they didn't think of this. It would've been nice if they'd allowed hostnames in security group rules but I just tried and that doesn't work. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided enough information to diagnose the problem, but there are a few things to check:

1. Is I-1 definitely in SG-1? If you've got the instances muddled, the SG rules would be around the wrong way.
2. Does the machine in SG-2 have a firewall running that might be blocking incoming traffic even though the SG rules are allowing it?
3. You've tagged this with the VPC tag - do you have any network ACL settings that might be preventing traffic flow? Are the machines private, using a NAT appliance to get out to the Internet, or public, routing through the standard AWS gateway? Can I-1 see the Internet? If you're routing through a NAT, assigning an EIP to a machine effectively cuts it off from the Internet because EIP and NAT are mutually incompatible, and although I haven't tried it this might also screw up SG routing.
4. Does SG-1 have any egress rules that might be preventing traffic from leaving?

The answer to your question is likely to be found in the resolution of one of these questions if the answer to any of them is 'Yes'.

Comment: Thanks for the diag help. This was repro'd on a bare account with nothing else present, here are the answers: 1. Yes 2. No firewall 3. No ACLs, no NAT, yes i-1 can see the internet. 4. No egress rules

These suggestions are helpful but didn't help in this case.

Answer (score -1):

As previously stated by [slayedbylucifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1251660/slayedbylucifer), you will need to explicitly allow traffic from the EIP.

Here's the reasoning from the [official AWS documentation about Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html):

> When you specify a security group as the source for a rule, traffic is allowed from the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group for the specified protocol and port. **Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses of the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).**